# Sort and remove the unnecessary nodes based on a shift code field value change and start and end date using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I need XSLT logic dealing with the below case, as I am unable to achieve this logic with the XSLT logic i used. Any help from you is greatly appreciated.

I have an employment data with many child <job_information> nodes, I need to basically remove the unnecessary nodes and filter only the required <job_information> records, based on the below criteria.

The Expected sorting is only based on the <Shift_Code>,<start_date>,<end_date> details

1. when <Shift_Code> field value exist and </Shift_Code_previous> is empty

in the above case , I have to consider only those records where <Shift_Code> field values not repeating (unique value), in this case I need to get those whole job information nodes where this <shift_Code> (eg: C02 and A02 exist).There is one more condition for similar records, that i need to fetch only those job information nodes where the <shift_code> is changed first (old date) based on start_date and end_date (i.e old one).

```
            <job_information><!--shift code changed-->
                <action>INSERT</action>
                <Shift_Code>C02</Shift_Code>
                <Shift_Code_previous/>
                <Emp_Band>Band 04</Emp_Band>
                <pay_grade>48</pay_grade>
                <end_date>2023-05-05</end_date>
                <start_date>2023-04-03</start_date>
            </job_information>
```

2. when <Shift_Code> field value exist and <Shift_Code_previous> field value also exist

in the above case , I have to consider only those <Shift_Code> field values which are not repeating (unique value), in this case I need to get those whole job information nodes where this <Shift_Code>B02</Shift_Code>,<Shift_Code_previous>A02</Shift_Code_previous> exist. There is one more condition for similar records, that i need to fetch only those job information nodes where the <shift_code> is changed first (old date) based on start_date and end_date (i.e old one).

```
            <job_information><!--shift code changed-->
                <action>CHANGE</action>
                <Shift_Code>B02</Shift_Code>
                <Shift_Code_previous>A02</Shift_Code_previous>
                <Emp_Band>Band 07</Emp_Band>
                <pay_grade>40</pay_grade>
                <end_date>2023-06-14</end_date>
                <start_date>2023-06-09</start_date>
            </job_information>
```

I have used the below XSLT logic but it is not yielding the correct result.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Person_Data>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//job_information[not(preceding-sibling::job_information[start_date &lt; current()/start_date or (start_date = current()/start_date and end_date &lt; current()/end_date)])]"/>
    </Person_Data>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="job_information">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

please find the below input payload and expected result:

Input payload :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Person_Data>
    <Record>
        <id>888</id>
        <person>
            <person_id>888</person_id>
            <person_id_external>58</person_id_external>
            <employment_information>
                <action>CHANGE</action>
                <employment_id>825</employment_id>
                <job_information><!--shift code not changed but repeated-->
                    <action>CHANGE</action>
                    <Shift_Code>B02</Shift_Code>
                    <Shift_Code_previous>A02</Shift_Code_previous>
                    <Emp_Band>Band 07</Emp_Band>
                    <Emp_Band_previous>Band 05</Emp_Band_previous>
                    <pay_grade>40</pay_grade>
                    <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                    <start_date>2023-06-24</start_date>
                </job_information>
                <job_information>
                    <action>CHANGE</action><!--shift code not changed but repeated-->
                    <Shift_Code>B02</Shift_Code>
                    <Shift_Code_previous>A02</Shift_Code_previous>
                    <Emp_Band>Band 07</Emp_Band>
                    <Emp_Band_previous>Band 05</Emp_Band_previous>
                    <pay_grade>40</pay_grade>
                    <end_date>2023-06-23</end_date>
                    <start_date>2023-06-15</start_date>
                </job_information>
                <job_information><!--shift code changed-->
                    <action>CHANGE</action>
                    <Shift_Code>B02</Shift_Code>
                    <Shift_Code_previous>A02</Shift_Code_previous>
                    <Emp_Band>Band 07</Emp_Band>
                    <pay_grade>40</pay_grade>
                    <end_date>2023-06-14</end_date>
                    <start_date>2023-06-09</start_date>
                </job_information>
                <job_information><!--shift code changed-->
                    <action>INSERT</action>
                    <Shift_Code>A02</Shift_Code>
                    <Shift_Code_previous/>
                    <Emp_Band>Band 05</Emp_Band>
                    <pay_grade>43</pay_grade>
                    <end_date>2023-05-10</end_date>
                    <start_date>2023-05-09</start_date>
                </job_information>
                <job_information><!--shift code not changed but repeated-->
                    <action>INSERT</action>
                    <Shift_Code>C02</Shift_Code>
                    <Shift_Code_previous/>
                    <Emp_Band>Band 05</Emp_Band>
                    <pay_grade>48</pay_grade>
                    <end_date>2023-05-05</end_date>
                    <start_date>2023-04-03</start_date>
                </job_information>
                <job_information><!--shift code changed-->
                    <action>INSERT</action>
                    <Shift_Code>C02</Shift_Code>
                    <Shift_Code_previous/>
                    <Emp_Band>Band 04</Emp_Band>
                    <pay_grade>48</pay_grade>
                    <end_date>2023-05-05</end_date>
                    <start_date>2023-04-03</start_date>
                </job_information>
            </employment_information>
        </person>
    </Record>
</Person_Data>
```

Output Payload :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Person_Data>
    <Record>
        <id>888</id>
        <person>
            <person_id>888</person_id>
            <person_id_external>58</person_id_external>
            <employment_information>
                <action>CHANGE</action>
                <employment_id>825</employment_id>
                <job_information><!--shift code changed-->
                    <action>CHANGE</action>
                    <Shift_Code>B02</Shift_Code>
                    <Shift_Code_previous>A02</Shift_Code_previous>
                    <Emp_Band>Band 07</Emp_Band>
                    <pay_grade>40</pay_grade>
                    <end_date>2023-06-14</end_date>
                    <start_date>2023-06-09</start_date>
                </job_information>
                <job_information><!--shift code changed-->
                    <action>INSERT</action>
                    <Shift_Code>A02</Shift_Code>
                    <Shift_Code_previous/>
                    <Emp_Band>Band 05</Emp_Band>
                    <pay_grade>43</pay_grade>
                    <end_date>2023-05-10</end_date>
                    <start_date>2023-05-09</start_date>
                </job_information>
                <job_information><!--shift code changed-->
                    <action>INSERT</action>
                    <Shift_Code>C02</Shift_Code>
                    <Shift_Code_previous/>
                    <Emp_Band>Band 04</Emp_Band>
                    <pay_grade>48</pay_grade>
                    <end_date>2023-05-05</end_date>
                    <start_date>2023-04-03</start_date>
                </job_information>
            </employment_information>
        </person>
    </Record>
</Person_Data>
```

Comment: Your business-rules are very hard to follow.
What would help is that you explain in the comments of Input payload **WHY** `shift code (not) changed (but repeated)`

Comment: Hi Siebe,Thanks for the response.I truncated the payload of the input so that it is feasible to understand. The reason why shift code (not) changed (but repeated) is that, there will be many fields in job information segment(say20),if any field value is changed a saperate Jobinfomation node with start and end date is created. That's reason the same shift code field value is getting carry forwarded to other nodes due to change in the other fields.I am only interested in the changes related to shift_code field values,so only when the shiftcode is changed,i need that particular start and end date